# build.sbt : Where is the 'project' object imported?

Tags: scala, sbt

In `build.sbt`, we can do `lazy val root = (project in file("."))`.

I know sbt does some imports but I can't find in the API doc how comes we can use directly the 'project' object.

Answer (score 3):

This is written in the [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Basic-Def.html#Imports+in+build.sbt):

```
import sbt._
import Process._
import Keys._
```

If you auto-complete `project` in IntelliJ IDEA, it brings you to trait `ProjectExtra`. This is available to due the fact that the `package object sbt` mixes in this trait. This is a bit hidden in the [API docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.7/api/index.html#sbt.package). But it's clear from [the source code](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.0.x/sbt/src/main/scala/package.scala#L4) (and [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.0.x/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Project.scala#L620)).